# ConEmu: Importing color schemes

Tags: windows, colors, conemu

Is there a way to import color schemes into ConEmu from other formats? E.g. there are many color schemes for iTerm 2 -- currently, if I wanted to use the colors from one of them, I'd have to manually enter the color values. Is there a simple way to convert an iTerm scheme to a ConEmu one? Or is there a similar place where I can look for ConEmu themes beyond the default ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, ConEmu can't import color schemes from other formats. You may

1. Enter color values one-by-one in the ConEmu Settings dialog, many formats are supported. For example, blue from Solarized scheme: `38 139 210` (dec values), `#268BD2` (hex values), `xD28B26` (another hex format).
2. If you use Windows Registry as ConEmu's setting storage, you may import your schemes with `*.reg` file. **Take care** about **"Count"** and **Palette1** if you want to store more than one scheme (change "Palette1" to "Palette2" and so on)! Example for Solarized scheme:

   ```
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ConEmu\.Vanilla\Colors]
   "Count"=dword:00000001
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ConEmu\.Vanilla\Colors\Palette1]
   "Name"="Solarized (Luke Maciak)"
   "ColorTable00"=dword:00423607
   "ColorTable01"=dword:00d28b26
   "ColorTable02"=dword:00009985
   "ColorTable03"=dword:000089b5
   "ColorTable04"=dword:002f32dc
   "ColorTable05"=dword:008236d3
   "ColorTable06"=dword:0098a12a
   "ColorTable07"=dword:00d5e8ee
   "ColorTable08"=dword:00362b00
   "ColorTable09"=dword:00aaa897
   "ColorTable10"=dword:00756e58
   "ColorTable11"=dword:00837b65
   "ColorTable12"=dword:00004ff2
   "ColorTable13"=dword:00c4716c
   "ColorTable14"=dword:00a1a193
   "ColorTable15"=dword:00e3f6fd
   ```
3. If you've choosed to store settings in `ConEmu.xml` file, you may add colors directly to your file with your fav editor. Same as for reg, **take care** about **"Count"** and **Palette1**. Example lines:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <key name="Software">
     <key name="ConEmu">
      <key name=".Vanilla">
       <key name="Colors">
        <!-- insertion point -->
        <value name="Count" type="dword" data="00000001"/>
        <key name="Palette1">
         <value name="Name" type="string" data="Solarized (Luke Maciak)"/>
         <value name="ColorTable00" type="dword" data="00423607"/>
         <value name="ColorTable01" type="dword" data="00d28b26"/>
         <value name="ColorTable02" type="dword" data="00009985"/>
         <value name="ColorTable03" type="dword" data="000089b5"/>
         <value name="ColorTable04" type="dword" data="002f32dc"/>
         <value name="ColorTable05" type="dword" data="008236d3"/>
         <value name="ColorTable06" type="dword" data="0098a12a"/>
         <value name="ColorTable07" type="dword" data="00d5e8ee"/>
         <value name="ColorTable08" type="dword" data="00362b00"/>
         <value name="ColorTable09" type="dword" data="00aaa897"/>
         <value name="ColorTable10" type="dword" data="00756e58"/>
         <value name="ColorTable11" type="dword" data="00837b65"/>
         <value name="ColorTable12" type="dword" data="00004ff2"/>
         <value name="ColorTable13" type="dword" data="00c4716c"/>
         <value name="ColorTable14" type="dword" data="00a1a193"/>
         <value name="ColorTable15" type="dword" data="00e3f6fd"/>
        </key>
      <!-- and so on... -->
   ```

Comment: If using ConEmu via another product, such as Cmder, be aware that color schemes should *not* be added to the "vendor" `ConEmu.xml` file noted at the top of Cmder's settings dialog, e.g., `C:\Users\me\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.xml`. Instead, custom settings should be added to the override file, e.g., `C:\Users\me\cmder_mini\config\ConEmu.xml`. This tripped me up when installing themes from https://github.com/joonro/ConEmu-Color-Themes . Don't forget to restart Cmder to update the configuration.

Comment: Oddly enough, I revisited my previous comment (from 2 years ago) for the same reason (couldn't figure out why ConEmu/Cmder wouldn't read my custom `ConEmu.xml`), and, this time, simply creating `C:\Users\me\cmder_mini\config\ConEmu.xml` had no effect. I had to delete `C:\Users\me\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.xml` (I'm not sure how this file is created in the first place, given that it doesn't exist in the `conemu` source) and then move my custom file to `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\ConEmu.xml`. Then, after restarting ConEmu, my custom `ConEmu.xml` became effective.